# Realm в Background

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

Возможно ли работа в **Realm** полностью в асинхронном потоке (если да то как это реализовать)

Никак не получается перевести Realm в Backround. Предусмотрен ли какой-нибудь функционал для этого? Или основную работу все равно надо делать в *main thread* ?

Основные задачи которые хочется реализовать это:

1. Запись данных в **Realm** в асинхронном потоке
2. Получение данных из **Realm** в асинхронном потоке
3. Создание наблюдателей и обновление данный у наблюдателей в **Realm** в асинхронном потоке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, возможно.
Просто всю работу с Realm делайте в асинхронном потоке.
Допустим у меня есть сервис DataStorage, который работает с Realm.
За все ваши пункты 1, 2 и 3 у меня отвечает класс DataStorage.
Обращение к нему я оборачиваю в

```
DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else {
            return
        }
        self.dataStorage.fetchSomeData()
}
```

Вы можете задать сами нужный вам thread:

```
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async { ... }
```

Здесь есть пример https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-notifications-on-background-threads-with-swift/ , как организовать observe на своем thread.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ, можете подробно описать создание observer в асинхронном потоке, у меня выдает ошибку run_loop если я пытаюсь создать observer в background.

Comment: @ВикторМишустин приложил ссылку на пример.

Comment: Интересный подход, сам бы не додумался, спасибо за ответ!